# How to handle operator precedence in LALR(1) parser

Tags: parsing, lalr

I was writing an LALR(1) parser for a simple arithmetic grammar

```
E -> E ('+' | '-') T
E -> T
T -> T ('*' | '/') F
T -> F
F -> '( E ')'
F -> int
```

How would I handle operator precedence for an expression such as 1 * 1 + 2 so that the 1+2 is evaluated before the multiplication?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to invert the preecedence? If so, what's wrong with the obvious solution where you just change the operator symbols in that grammar?

Comment: No like when I implement the parser, how would I enforce the precedence?

Comment: The precedence is defined by the grammar. But the grammar makes `*` bind more tightly. Which is the way arithmetic works. `1*1+2` isn't a good example because it has the same result both ways.